# Correct way to modify php.ini for Apache and/or CLI

Tags: 16.04, apache2, php

I want to change and add some PHP directives, some for apache, some for CLI and some for both. As an example, I want to set the default timezone for all server contexts. There are a couple of different ways I can go about this, but I don't know which is the best approach.

I can directly edit the master php.ini files, which are here `/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini` and here `/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini`, but I don't know whether this file will be overwritten on upgrade. Also for shared settings, such as the timezone, I have to remember to edit two files and keep those changes synchronised.

I can use Apache's `php_admin_value`, `php_admin_flag`, `php_value` and `php_flag` directives. The advantage here is that the php settings can be applied on a virtual host by virtual host basis and I can also apply them globally to Apache. However, this doesn't help with the CLI settings.

The php directory has a similar structure to Apache, allowing files full of directives to be enabled or disabled with the `phpenmod` command. I can copy this structure, creating the directory `/etc/php/7.0/mydirectives`, placing `php.ini` files within this folder, then creating symbolic links from `/etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/` to my php.ini directive files. This allows me to have a single directive file which adds directives to **both** Apache and CLI version of PHP. The only thing I can't do with this is virtual host by virtual directives.

Any advice on how to do this properly?

Answer (score 5):

FYI, [configuration](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Configuration) files in `/etc/` installed by a package are not overwritten by default; on upgrade if a file changes a prompt is presented with [options](https://raphaelhertzog.com/2010/09/21/debian-conffile-configuration-file-managed-by-dpkg/).

Coming back to the original question, here is how I would do it:

- Create a config file `/etc/php/7.0/mods-available/50-mydirectives.ini` and do common configuration there; then use `phpenmod mydirectives` to enable it.
- Do `apache` and `cli` specific configuration in `/etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/` and `/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/` respectively.
- Do virtualhost specific configuration in the virtualhost itself.

With the above configuration will not need to edit system provided `php.ini`.

Related:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13383806/what-the-ini-files-in-etc-php5-conf-d-folder-are-for
- https://duraturk.wordpress.com/2014/04/27/php5enmod/

Comment: `phpenmod` can enable configs for just a given SAPI if you use `-s` option, so even FPM or CLI  specific config can be kept in `/etc/php/7.0/mods-available/` and enabled per-SAPI.